# What is the fastest T Stop available?

Tags: optics, light-transmission

What is the widest T Stop possible We are having f stops of below even 0.7 NASA lenses What will be the T stop of such lenses with f stop below ONE?

Comment: Some of this is covered under [What is special about lenses with f-number < 1?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/what-is-special-about-lenses-with-f-number-1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not try to solve an actual problem (see [Don't Ask](http://photo.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in Help).

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you want?  Photolithography lenses are sitting around f/0.6 consistently these days and they have almost perfect transmission, so t/0.65 or so.  You can buy microscope objectives faster than f/0.4 these days as well, though they require immersion oil to function.  These systems again have very fast t/#s.  In the consumer marketplace?  t/1.2 is about as good as you will do with some of the very fast cinema lenses, or a used Canon 50mm f/1.0L which should be around t/1.1-t/1.2 or so.  Most of the f/0.95 lenses available are probably closer to f/1.05 and have strong losses, so t/1.1 would be about right.