# Are there lenses f/1 or wider that work on EF or E-mount?

Tags: lens, aperture, sony, fast-lenses

Which lenses have apertures at f/1 or better, and work on cameras like the 6D or A7?

In Sony's case, an adapter is acceptable.

Comment: It is a little strange that you are looking for that kind of lens: http://www.thephoblographer.com/2013/08/06/14-super-fast-aperture-lenses-worthy-of-note/#.Vi3PbCt5Hwg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Canon EF mount you have pretty much only one option, the EF 50mm f/1.0L, which went out of production in 2000.

For the e-mount you could adapt a huge number of lenses, good choices would be

- Mitakon Speedmaster 50mm f/0.95 (native E-mount)
- SLR Magic 50mm f/0.95 Hyperprime Lens (native E-mount)
- SLR Magic 35mm f/0.95 Hyperprime Lens (native E-mount)
- HandeVision Ibelux 40mm f/0.85 (native E-Mount)
- Canon 50mm f/0.95 (FD mount)
- Leica Noctilux 50mm f/0.95 ASPH (M-mount)

Comment: What's up with all the F/0.95. Isn't F/1 close enough? Seems like an odd number for an aperture.

Comment: Thanks for the list. Nothing around 24mm, huh?

Comment: @Itai f/0.95 just sounds better, it's *faster* than f/1!

Comment: @icor103 Not that covers at least APS-C. There's a Voigtlander 25mm f/0.95 but that only covers micro 4/3rds. SLR magic make the widest f/0.95 for APS-C at 35mm.

Comment: the rear opening has to be larger for a larger aperture. the mount size pretty much limits this.  only a few pro camera lines allow larger (makes the camera line more expensive).  i have heard of a cinema camera that handle lenses down to f/0.7 ... you might be able to do better on an APS-C sensor.

Comment: It's weird that this lens isn't well known : Carl Zeiss Super-Q-Gigantar **0.33**/40mm ->http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12072/what-is-special-about-lenses-with-f-number-1

Comment: @Olivier probably because it's a mock up (built as a sort of joke) out of old condenser lenses, not an actual lens you could use. The focal length and aperture stats were made up.

Comment: @mattgrum, I know, that's why it is awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

Someone has this Rayxar 50mm f/0.75 with a custom E-mount adapter for sale on eBay at the moment: http://www.ebay.com/itm/191743971223

Sounds like a quirky lens though. Fixed-focus and fixed-aperture, it was originally used for x-rays. Has a dreamlike effect to the photos it produces.